# How to create buttons in a textfield just like in the Mail app?

Tags: swift, macos, textfield

**Background:** When you open the Mail.app and compose a new email, in the `To:` textfield when you start typing you see regular text characters. However when it recognizes a name a list pops up and when you select an e-mailadress the text you typed converts into a blue button with it's own options and you are able to rearrange it with other blue buttons by clicking and dragging.

**Intention:** I like a user to drag elements into a textfield, which they can rearrange and combine with normal text characters.

For example, let's say we have an element `First Name` and an element `Last Name`. They can drag this in to the textfield where they become blue buttons. They can then edit the textfield to say something like: [ Hello `First Name` `Last Name`, ]

**Question:** How can I create these blue buttons within a textfield?

[image]

Comment: That's [NSTokenField](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/) and this is the [Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#). It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @vadian could you please post your comment as an answer? I didn't know it existed hopefully my question will help others searching for the same thing.

Comment: Done, and I added the `osx` tag to make sure the question is not related to iOS